# How to change iOS app "developed by" name?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-appstore, developer-program

I have developed an iOS app using Phonegap technology. I have uploaded it on Apple App Store & it has been approved, is ready for sale & is live on AppStore. The problem is that I want to change developed by name of the app. How do we change it? Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Must contact Apple Support to do it.

> #### How can I update or change my iOS Developer Program account information?
>
> Please [contact us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) for assistance with:
>
> - Address changes
> - Contact information updates
> - Company/Organization name updates or changes

[Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php)